# how to pass navigation prop to map(function()) of array?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Getting

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.props.navigation')

error while click on TouchableOpacity.

```
render() {
     List = this.state.availableList.map(function(demo){
     return(
       <View key={(exam, index) => index.toString()} >
         <TouchableOpacity 
           onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('BCD')} >
           <View>
             <Text>{demo.Name}</Text>
             <Text>{demo.Address}</Text>
           </View>
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
     );
   });
  return (
<View>
{List}
</View>

    );
  }
```

in map(function()) this.props.navigation not getting so my question is how to pass props ?

Comment: `this.state.availableList.map((demo) => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its better to use arrow funtion in the `map` as shown below.

```
render() {
     List = this.state.availableList.map(demo =>{
     return(
       <View key={(exam, index) => index.toString()} >
         <TouchableOpacity 
           onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('BCD')} >
           <View>
             <Text>{demo.Name}</Text>
             <Text>{demo.Address}</Text>
           </View>
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
     );
   });
  return (
<View>
{List}
</View>

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use an arrow function for your map

```
this.state.availableList.map( (demo) => {
```

applied to your render

```
const { availableList } = this.state
return (
  <View>
    availableList.map( (demo) => {
    return(
        <View key={(exam, index) => index.toString()} >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('BCD')} >
            <View>
              <Text>{demo.Name}</Text>
              <Text>{demo.Address}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    })}
  </View>

  );
}
```